# How to retreive client's IP using Google appscript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-developer-tools

I want to retreive the public IP address of the machine on which my Google Calendar addon developed using Google appscript is being used. How Can I do so inside the code using Google Appscript? Is there any method or way to do so?

Comment: I don't think that's possible and even if it was how could you be sure that your clients is not using a VPN.

Answer (score 0):

I get the client IP in my WebApp using [ipinfo.io](https://ipinfo.io/).  I don't know whether that can work in an addon.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following code for example:

```js
function getIP() {
  let html = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://www.whatsmyip.org/').getContentText();
  let ip = new RegExp('id="ip">(.*?)<').exec(html)[0].substring(8).split("<")[0];
  console.log(ip);
}
```

---

#### References:

- [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)

Comment: The script displays me the IP address of Williams Information Technology LLC or Merit Network Inc. Mayby it is servers of Google?